# How big is the difference in performance between these two Queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

I have the following [two Queries](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c36a8/22/0):

```
SELECT id
FROM t
ORDER BY col = 'A' DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

**AND**

```
SELECT id
FROM t
ORDER BY CASE WHEN 'A' LIKE CONCAT(col, '%') THEN col END DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

The Two gives the same result with and without the `LIMIT 1`, What is the difference between those two Queries in Performance? The **2nd Query** is useful with **multiple word** But with a **single-word** both Queries does the same effect on the `ORDER`.

Is there any difference That it is better If I used the **1st Query** for `Single-Word` If I could?

Comment: Those are not as equivalent as you think; the latter will only order by the `col` value when that value = 'A'.

Comment: @Uueerdo The `2nd Query` costs a lot as I suppose?

Comment: `'A' LIKE 'Abracadabra%'` is false; but, yes, the latter is more expensive (LIKE is generally more expensive than `=`, and you're adding concatenation of a field value on top of that).

Comment: what's the goal of the query?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu I was trying to `ORDER` the Table values by `String`'s words, I asked a Question aobut how to do that before here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/204337/144584 And the answer was promising in results.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu the `String` isn't static, Sometime I'll want `B` first or `C` first, And it is a Variable String, It is a user-defined value.

Comment: @Uueerdo So I better use `column = 'word'` If it is a **single-word/letter**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't expect any measurable difference in performance. This is a full scan of all rows in `t`, to retrieve the columns `id` and `col`. (This could be a scan of the table, or a covering index.)

The `ORDER BY` can't be satisfied from an index; either way, we're going to be seeing a "Using filesort" operation in the `EXPLAIN` output.

The equality comparison may be marginally less work than the `CONCAT` and `LIKE` comparison.

But the queries are significantly different.

The `CASE` expression is returning values of `col` or `NULL`. The query ordering the result of an equality comparison is returning 1, 0 or NULL.

There might be a difference in the performance of the sort operation, one is sorting integers, the second is sorting whatever datatype `col` is.

---

With trivial sets, no measurable difference in performance.

With huge sets, both queries may have horrendous performance.

I suspect a *different* query would satisfy the specification much more efficiently than either of the options.

---

But why do we need an `ORDER BY` at all? There's a `LIMIT 1`.  So we're returning an `id` value. That could be from a row with `col='A'`, or not.

Before we get too worked up about which is faster, we should make sure we are satisfying the specification.

I strongly suspect that the spec could be tweaked to entirely *avoid* a potentially expensive sort operation, to return just one `id` value.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

The specification that this query satisfies isn't clear; the reason for running this query.

Why are we returning just one `id` value? We are wanting to return an `id` value of a row that "matches" a string. And if there isn't a row that matches, then return the `id` of a row in the table with a non-NULL `col` value. And if there isn't a row with a non-NULL `col` value, then return `id` of any row in the table.

(The first query in the question is different from the second, in regards to case 2 and 3... the row that gets returned in the case of no matching `col` values, NULL vs non-NULL.)

Comment: by `huge sets` Do you mean if I have a lot of Records in the Table Or if I removed the `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: @Toleo, reading 1 millions rows but returning only 1... therefore you need a `where clause`

Comment: By "huge sets" i mean the number of rows accessed, and in this case, sorted. (I'm not sure that MySQL has an "early out" optimization for the `LIMIT 1` special case, which would require only identifying the row with the "highest" value, not sorting the entire set. But what we are sorting on is an expression that has to be evaluated. In the general case, that means we need to evaluate the expression for every row in the table; we can't know we have the "highest" value for the expression without doing the evaluation.

Comment: We recognize that `a=b` can return only three possible values: 1,0 and NULL. I'm not sure MySQL optimizer is smart enough to recognize that once it finds a row where the expression evaluates to "1", it can use an early-out to return that row... without evaluating that expression for every row in the table, just in case it might return 2 or 7 or something else.

Answer (score 1):

This simple structure should suffice. You don't need to complicate stuff.

Problem with this statement, without the `where clause` is that you are returning all rows and then cutting the result to 1.. which means 1 million rows to read but get the first one.

```
SELECT id
FROM t
ORDER BY col = 'A' DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

or optimize with

```
SELECT id
FROM t
where instr('A',col) > 0
ORDER BY col
LIMIT 1;
```

Will get the matching rows but return only 1 row. so from 1 million rows, 300 rows where matched then get the 1st one.

Comment: Wouldn't `WHERE col = 'A'` does the same as `WHERE  instr('A', col) > 0` ?

Comment: nope.. that's a `filesort` not a filter while `instr` is a filter

Comment: Can it be used to apply the same results of this Query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c36a8/45/0 ? but in `WHERE`?

Comment: what string are you looking for?

Comment: It is about getting data by a `String` parts As I made a Question about it here https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/204323/144584 , I'm supposed to get records for example If i used the string `A B C` to I want to get all records has `A B C` and `A B` and `A`. in `col`

Comment: Didn't think it would affect the Question overall, Since I was concerned about performance, Will add it now.

Comment: I guess I'll have to make a Question on how to optimize the 2nd-Query now?

Comment: in deed. with all the scenarios you want

Answer (score 0):

In both cases

1. The entire table is read.  The larger the table, the longer the query takes.
2. The `ORDER BY` clause is evaluated for every row.  (The second option would take slightly longer to to the evaluation.)
3. The rows are sorted.
4. One row is delivered.

Furthermore, the two queries are *not* equivalent.

- `ORDER BY col = 'A' DESC` -- deliver the rows where `col='A'` first
- The other query delivers rows with `col='A'`, then rows with `col=''`.

You *may* see a difference, even with `LIMIT 1` if the table does not have any row with `col='A'`.

If you got the same results, it was coincidence.

What do you mean by "single-word"?  In `col`?  In `A`?  Something else?

`where instr('A',col) > 0` will also require a full table scan.  It will catch `col` equal to 'A' or ''.  This is *not* the same as testing `col='A'`.